# Maximum client sockets

Tags: http, networking, tcp

I was reading tod lammales CCNA study guide 6th edition and stumbled upon this,

> One thing to remember is that if multiple hosts are communication to
>   the server using HTTP, they must all use a different source port
>   number.That is how the web server keep the data separated at the
>   transport layer.      *page 337*

Can this be true ? Because i always thought Ip and port number makes a unique endpoint at TCP layer, but according to this even for incoming connections from different source IPs, source port must be different ! appreciate your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't true. But what you said isn't true either. TCP connections are identified by the tuple {local address, local port, remote address, remote port}, not by any one of those, or two. What you have quoted, if accurate, would be (a) complete nonsense and (b) entirely unimplementable. How are all those clients going to co-ordinate amongst themselves to always use different source ports?